# how to upload scraped data through beautifulsoup4 to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#import question from stack overflow
htp='https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=2'

response=requests.get(htp).text
soup=Beautiful Soup(response,"HTML.parser")
#class question-summary...

question=soup.select("question-summary")

#open csv file....

with open("new.csv","w") as file:
write=csv.writer(file)
write.writerow(["heading","summary","votes"])

for ques in question:
    print(ques.select_one("question-hyperlink").getText())
    print(ques.select_one("excerpt").getText())
    print(ques.select_one("vote-count-post").getText())
    
    #problem area
    write.writerow...???( what to do)
```

Comment: Andrej Kesely can you help me??

Comment: Yes, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To save the data to CSV, you can use this example:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#import question from stack overflow
htp='https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=2'

response=requests.get(htp).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

#class question-summary...
question=soup.select(".question-summary")

#open csv file....
with open("new.csv", "w") as file:
    write=csv.writer(file)
    write.writerow(["heading","summary","votes"])

    for ques in question:
        heading = ques.select_one(".question-hyperlink").getText()
        summary = ques.select_one(".excerpt").getText()
        votes = ques.select_one(".vote-count-post").getText()

        print(heading)
        print(summary)
        print(votes)
        
        write.writerow([heading, summary, votes])
```

Creates `new.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: thank you.....whice one should i use to scrap.Beautifulsoup,selenium or scrapy?

Comment: @learner Depends on the situation - Selenium uses real browser, so it can execute javascript (maybe that's what you want). BeautifulSoup can't do it, but it's faster and less resource hungry. I don't have experience with Scrapy...